# Java Struts2 - How do I create an arraylist using struts tags, to be populated by user then the values should be passed to action?

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, struts2, struts-action

I'm a newbie in Struts 2 and I want to create an arraylist in JSP using Struts tags. And then, the values inputted should be passed to an action. Also, how do I get it back from action into JSP?

**Bean**

```
public class BookingListAction extends ActionSupport {

    private Boolean isDebit;
    private BigDecimal amount;
    private BigDecimal phpAmount;
    private String currency;
    private String glAccountName;
    private BigDecimal glAccountNumber;
    private String misCode;
    private String branchCode;
    private String branchName;

    public Boolean getIsDebit() {
        return isDebit;
    }

    public void setIsDebit(Boolean isDebit) {
        this.isDebit = isDebit;
    }

    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPhpAmount() {
        return phpAmount;
    }

    public void setPhpAmount(BigDecimal phpAmount) {
        this.phpAmount = phpAmount;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getGlAccountName() {
        return glAccountName;
    }

    public void setGlAccountName(String glAccountName) {
        this.glAccountName = glAccountName;
    }

    public BigDecimal getGlAccountNumber() {
        return glAccountNumber;
    }

    public void setGlAccountNumber(BigDecimal glAccountNumber) {
        this.glAccountNumber = glAccountNumber;
    }

    public String getMisCode() {
        return misCode;
    }

    public void setMisCode(String misCode) {
        this.misCode = misCode;
    }

    public String getBranchCode() {
        return branchCode;
    }

    public void setBranchCode(String branchCode) {
        this.branchCode = branchCode;
    }

    public String getBranchName() {
        return branchName;
    }

    public void setBranchName(String branchName) {
        this.branchName = branchName;
    }
}
```

**Action**

```
public class BookingAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<BookingListAction> bookingList = new ArrayList<BookingListAction>();

    public String execute() {

        try {
            getBookingList();
            System.out.println(getBookingList());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public List<BookingListAction> getBookingList() {
        return bookingList;
    }

    public void setBookingList(List<BookingListAction> bookingList) {
        this.bookingList = bookingList;
    }

}
```

**JSP**

```xml
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<form id="bookingDebitCreditForm" action="BookingDebitCredit" method="POST">

    <s:textfield name="bookingListItem['0'].amount"/>

    <s:iterator value="bookingList" var="bookingListItem" status="key">
        <s:textfield name="bookingListItem[%{#key.index}].amount"/>
    </s:iterator>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat btn-info" id="saveBookingJson">save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-raised">back</button> 

</form>
```

The problem is I don't know how can the user be able to input a value in my arraylist. And how can I get it from JSP so I can use it in my action? Thank you in advance.

**New JSP**

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<form id="bookingDebitCreditForm" action="BookingDebitCredit" method="POST">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Amount: 
                </td>
                <td>
                    <s:textfield name="bookingList[%{#key.index}].amount" theme="simple"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <table> 
            <s:iterator value="bookingDebitCreditList" id="array" status="key">
              <tr>
                  <td><s:textfield name="array[%{#key.index}].amount" value="%{amount}" theme="simple"/></td>
              </tr>
            </s:iterator>
            </table>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-info">save</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-raised">back</button> 

</form>
```

**Action**

```
    package pnb.cdo.booking.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import pnb.cdo.booking.service.BookingService;
import pnb.cdo.model.BookingBean;
import pnb.cdo.model.BookingDebitCreditBean;

/**
 * @author MSICX420
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BookingAction extends ActionSupport {

    private List<BookingListBean> bookingList = new ArrayList<BookingListBean>();
    private List<BookingDebitCreditBean> bookingDebitCreditList = new ArrayList<BookingDebitCreditBean>();

    public String execute() {

        BookingBean bookingBean = new BookingBean();
        BookingDebitCreditBean bookingDebitCreditBean = new BookingDebitCreditBean();

        Integer ctr = 0;
        for (BookingListBean item : bookingList) {
            bookingDebitCreditBean.setAmount(bookingList.get(ctr).getAmount());
            bookingDebitCreditBean.setBookingBean(bookingBean);
        }

        bookingDebitCreditList = BookingService.getAllBookingDebitCredit();
        for (BookingDebitCreditBean item : bookingDebitCreditList) {
            System.out.println(item.getAmount());
        }

        if (BookingService.isBookingDebitCreditAdded(bookingDebitCreditBean)) {
            return SUCCESS;
        }

        return NONE;
    }

    /**
     * Getters and setters
     */
    public List<BookingListBean> getBookingList() {
        return bookingList;
    }

    public void setBookingList(List<BookingListBean> bookingList) {
        this.bookingList = bookingList;
    }

    public List<BookingDebitCreditBean> getBookingDebitCreditList() {
        return bookingDebitCreditList;
    }

    public void setBookingDebitCreditList(List<BookingDebitCreditBean> bookingDebitCreditList) {
        this.bookingDebitCreditList = bookingDebitCreditList;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close in the JSP, but really far in the `Action`:

#### Action

1. A POJO shouldn't extend `ActionSupport` (in the same way as an `Action` shouldn't contain a List of actions);
2. An action method should never return `null`, it should instead return a result mapped to a JSP or some other view, eg. `return SUCCESS;`
3. The `getBookingList();` alone doesn't make any sense;
4. The `System.out.println(getBookingList());` won't print the details (eg. `amount`) of each element, search how to do it properly;

#### JSP

5. You need to target the action attribute, not the object pushed by the iterator with `var=""`, hence:

   ```xml
    <s:textfield name="bookingList[%{#key.index}].amount"/>
   ```
6. The rest is right; you need to create an `<s:textfield />` (or an `<s:hidden/>`) for each field you need to send to the target action.

Comment: Thank you for your comments sir. It helped a lot :) I followed every step but it seems I'm having problem understanding item number 5. Since I'm using an ArrayList in my JSP, how do I get the value from the JSP so I can use it in my action? TIA. `<s:textfield name="bookingList[%{#key.index}].amount"/>`

Comment: That code does exactly that : bookingList addresses the arraylist, [number] specifies which element, and .amount the property. What is not working? P. S. You obviously need that arraylist in the target action too, if different from the source one

Comment: For some reason, I cannot get the value from my JSP when I check it on debug mode, the amount field is null. I've added above the new JSP and action btw. Thank you.

Comment: The first s:textfield is OUTSIDE of the iterator, hence key.index has no meaning there. In the other instead there is `array[...]`. What is array ? You need bookingList: `<s:textfield name="bookingList[%{#key.index}].amount"/>`